# Improper transition along path in d3 with leaflet

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

With the help of d3 v3, i'm trying to create plane animations over leaflet osm map. These are the codes i'm using to rotate and move plane element over path between 2 locations. Planes are moving along path but they are not in proper alignment.
Here is the complete code :

```js
var defaultlocation = [28.6139, 77.2090];
var defaultzoom = 5;
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: defaultlocation, // default map location //
  zoom: defaultzoom,
  minZoom: 2
});

var mbAttr = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
  mbUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var mapTileLayer = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
  attribution: mbAttr
});

map.addLayer(mapTileLayer);

map._initPathRoot();

var w = $("#map").innerWidth();
var h = $("#map").innerHeight();

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).select(".leaflet-zoom-animated");

var cords = [{
  id: 1,
  lat: 28.6139,
  lon: 77.2090
}, {
  id: 2,
  lat: 19.0760,
  lon: 72.8777
}];

var links = [{
  source: 1,
  target: 2
}];

for (var i in cords) {
  cords[i].LatLng = new L.LatLng(cords[i].lat, cords[i].lon);
}

var linkgroup = svg.selectAll(".linkgroup")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "linkgroup");

var planes = linkgroup.append("path")
  .attr("class", "plane")
  .attr("visibility", "hidden")
  .attr("d", "m25.21488,3.93375c-0.44355,0 -0.84275,0.18332 -1.17933,0.51592c-0.33397,0.33267 -0.61055,0.80884 -0.84275,1.40377c-0.45922,1.18911 -0.74362,2.85964 -0.89755,4.86085c-0.15655,1.99729 -0.18263,4.32223 -0.11741,6.81118c-5.51835,2.26427 -16.7116,6.93857 -17.60916,7.98223c-1.19759,1.38937 -0.81143,2.98095 -0.32874,4.03902l18.39971,-3.74549c0.38616,4.88048 0.94192,9.7138 1.42461,13.50099c-1.80032,0.52703 -5.1609,1.56679 -5.85232,2.21255c-0.95496,0.88711 -0.95496,3.75718 -0.95496,3.75718l7.53,-0.61316c0.17743,1.23545 0.28701,1.95767 0.28701,1.95767l0.01304,0.06557l0.06002,0l0.13829,0l0.0574,0l0.01043,-0.06557c0,0 0.11218,-0.72222 0.28961,-1.95767l7.53164,0.61316c0,0 0,-2.87006 -0.95496,-3.75718c-0.69044,-0.64577 -4.05363,-1.68813 -5.85133,-2.21516c0.48009,-3.77545 1.03061,-8.58921 1.42198,-13.45404l18.18207,3.70115c0.48009,-1.05806 0.86881,-2.64965 -0.32617,-4.03902c-0.88969,-1.03062 -11.81147,-5.60054 -17.39409,-7.89352c0.06524,-2.52287 0.04175,-4.88024 -0.1148,-6.89989l0,-0.00476c-0.15655,-1.99844 -0.44094,-3.6683 -0.90277,-4.8561c-0.22699,-0.59493 -0.50356,-1.07111 -0.83754,-1.40377c-0.33658,-0.3326 -0.73578,-0.51592 -1.18194,-0.51592l0,0l-0.00001,0l0,0z");

var linkpath = linkgroup.append('path')
  .attr("class", "linkpath")
  .style("fill", "none");

var markergroup = svg.selectAll(".markergroup")
  .data(cords)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "markergroup")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("mousedown", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });


var markercircle = markergroup.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "markercircle")
  .on("mousedown", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });





function getcordsbyid(id) {
  for (var i in cords) {
    if (cords[i].id == id) {
      return cords[i].LatLng;
    }
  }
}

map.on("viewreset", update);
update();
fly(1, 2, true);

function transition(plane, route, nonstop) {
  var l = route.node().getTotalLength();
  plane.attr("visibility", "visible");
  plane.transition()
    .duration(l * 30)
    .attrTween("transform", delta(plane, route.node()))
    .each("end", function() {
      if (nonstop) {
        transition(plane, route, nonstop);
      } else {
        plane.attr("visibility", "hidden");
      }
    });
}

function delta(plane, path) {
  return function(i) {
    return function(t) {
      var l = path.getTotalLength();
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);

      var t2 = Math.min(t + 0.05, 1);
      var p2 = path.getPointAtLength(t2 * l);

      var x = p2.x - p.x;
      var y = p2.y - p.y;
      var r = 90 - Math.atan2(-y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;

      var s = Math.min(Math.sin(Math.PI * t) * 0.7, 0.5);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ") scale(" + s + ") rotate(" + r + ")";
    }
  }
}

function fly(sourceid, targetid, nonstop) {
  linkgroup.filter(function(l) {
    if (l.source == sourceid && l.target == targetid) {
      return l;
    }
  }).each(function(l) {
    var route = d3.select(this).select(".linkpath");
    var plane = d3.select(this).select(".plane");
    transition(plane, route, nonstop);
  });

}


function update() {

  markergroup.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var cor = map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng);
    return "translate(" + cor.x + "," + cor.y + ")";
  });


  linkgroup.each(function(d, i) {
    var route = d3.select(this).select(".linkpath").attr("d", function(l) {
      var slatlong = map.latLngToLayerPoint(getcordsbyid(l.source));
      var tlatlong = map.latLngToLayerPoint(getcordsbyid(l.target));

      var dx = tlatlong.x - slatlong.x,
        dy = tlatlong.y - slatlong.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * 3;
      return "M" + slatlong.x + "," + slatlong.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
        " 0 0,1 " + tlatlong.x + "," + tlatlong.y;
    });
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.linkpath {
  stroke: #FF2EB9;
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 10;
  stroke-width: 2
}

.markercircle {
  stroke: black;
  fill: green;
  r: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plane {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Is there any fault in the delta() or it is because i'm not using geojson path?

Answer (score 3):

Right now the animation is correct: if you look at the tip of the plane's left wing, it's right over the pink line.

The problem, therefore, is that you are not taking into account the **size** of the plane's `<path>` element itself.

A simple solution is getting its width:

```
var planesSize = planes.node().getBBox().width;
```

And changing the return of the `delta` function:

```
return "translate(" + (p.x + (planesSize / 2 * s)) + 
    "," + (p.y + (planesSize / 2 * s)) + ") scale(" + s + ") rotate(" + r + ")";
```

Here is the code with those changes:

```js
var defaultlocation = [28.6139, 77.2090];
var defaultzoom = 5;
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: defaultlocation, // default map location //
  zoom: defaultzoom,
  minZoom: 2
});

var mbAttr = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
  mbUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var mapTileLayer = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
  attribution: mbAttr
});

map.addLayer(mapTileLayer);

map._initPathRoot();

var w = $("#map").innerWidth();
var h = $("#map").innerHeight();

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).select(".leaflet-zoom-animated");

var cords = [{
  id: 1,
  lat: 28.6139,
  lon: 77.2090
}, {
  id: 2,
  lat: 19.0760,
  lon: 72.8777
}];

var links = [{
  source: 1,
  target: 2
}];

for (var i in cords) {
  cords[i].LatLng = new L.LatLng(cords[i].lat, cords[i].lon);
}

var linkgroup = svg.selectAll(".linkgroup")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "linkgroup");

var linkpath = linkgroup.append('path')
  .attr("class", "linkpath")
  .style("fill", "none");

var planes = linkgroup.append("path")
  .attr("class", "plane")
  .attr("visibility", "hidden")
  .attr("d", "m25.21488,3.93375c-0.44355,0 -0.84275,0.18332 -1.17933,0.51592c-0.33397,0.33267 -0.61055,0.80884 -0.84275,1.40377c-0.45922,1.18911 -0.74362,2.85964 -0.89755,4.86085c-0.15655,1.99729 -0.18263,4.32223 -0.11741,6.81118c-5.51835,2.26427 -16.7116,6.93857 -17.60916,7.98223c-1.19759,1.38937 -0.81143,2.98095 -0.32874,4.03902l18.39971,-3.74549c0.38616,4.88048 0.94192,9.7138 1.42461,13.50099c-1.80032,0.52703 -5.1609,1.56679 -5.85232,2.21255c-0.95496,0.88711 -0.95496,3.75718 -0.95496,3.75718l7.53,-0.61316c0.17743,1.23545 0.28701,1.95767 0.28701,1.95767l0.01304,0.06557l0.06002,0l0.13829,0l0.0574,0l0.01043,-0.06557c0,0 0.11218,-0.72222 0.28961,-1.95767l7.53164,0.61316c0,0 0,-2.87006 -0.95496,-3.75718c-0.69044,-0.64577 -4.05363,-1.68813 -5.85133,-2.21516c0.48009,-3.77545 1.03061,-8.58921 1.42198,-13.45404l18.18207,3.70115c0.48009,-1.05806 0.86881,-2.64965 -0.32617,-4.03902c-0.88969,-1.03062 -11.81147,-5.60054 -17.39409,-7.89352c0.06524,-2.52287 0.04175,-4.88024 -0.1148,-6.89989l0,-0.00476c-0.15655,-1.99844 -0.44094,-3.6683 -0.90277,-4.8561c-0.22699,-0.59493 -0.50356,-1.07111 -0.83754,-1.40377c-0.33658,-0.3326 -0.73578,-0.51592 -1.18194,-0.51592l0,0l-0.00001,0l0,0z");

var planesSize = planes.node().getBBox().width;

var markergroup = svg.selectAll(".markergroup")
  .data(cords)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "markergroup")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("mousedown", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });


var markercircle = markergroup.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "markercircle")
  .on("mousedown", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });





function getcordsbyid(id) {
  for (var i in cords) {
    if (cords[i].id == id) {
      return cords[i].LatLng;
    }
  }
}

map.on("viewreset", update);
update();
fly(1, 2, true);

function transition(plane, route, nonstop) {
  var l = route.node().getTotalLength();
  plane.attr("visibility", "visible");
  plane.transition()
    .duration(l * 30)
    .attrTween("transform", delta(plane, route.node()))
    .each("end", function() {
      if (nonstop) {
        transition(plane, route, nonstop);
      } else {
        plane.attr("visibility", "hidden");
      }
    });
}

function delta(plane, path) {
  return function(i) {
    return function(t) {
      var l = path.getTotalLength();
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);

      var t2 = Math.min(t + 0.05, 1);
      var p2 = path.getPointAtLength(t2 * l);

      var x = p2.x - p.x;
      var y = p2.y - p.y;
      var r = 90 - Math.atan2(-y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;

      var s = Math.min(Math.sin(Math.PI * t) * 0.7, 0.5);
      return "translate(" + (p.x + (planesSize / 2 * s)) + "," + (p.y + (planesSize / 2 * s)) + ") scale(" + s + ") rotate(" + r + ")";
    }
  }
}

function fly(sourceid, targetid, nonstop) {
  linkgroup.filter(function(l) {
    if (l.source == sourceid && l.target == targetid) {
      return l;
    }
  }).each(function(l) {
    var route = d3.select(this).select(".linkpath");
    var plane = d3.select(this).select(".plane");
    transition(plane, route, nonstop);
  });

}


function update() {

  markergroup.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var cor = map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng);
    return "translate(" + cor.x + "," + cor.y + ")";
  });


  linkgroup.each(function(d, i) {
    var route = d3.select(this).select(".linkpath").attr("d", function(l) {
      var slatlong = map.latLngToLayerPoint(getcordsbyid(l.source));
      var tlatlong = map.latLngToLayerPoint(getcordsbyid(l.target));

      var dx = tlatlong.x - slatlong.x,
        dy = tlatlong.y - slatlong.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * 3;
      return "M" + slatlong.x + "," + slatlong.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
        " 0 0,1 " + tlatlong.x + "," + tlatlong.y;
    });
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.linkpath {
  stroke: #FF2EB9;
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 10;
  stroke-width: 2
}

.markercircle {
  stroke: black;
  fill: green;
  r: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plane {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

**PS**: Append the plane's path **after** the route's path. Otherwise, the plane will fly under the route, not over it.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, You've resolved it. I was trying to trick the same inside the delta() but not getting success.. //var sz = plane.node().getBBox();
//p.x = p.x + (sz.width/2) -s ;
//p.y = p.y + (sz.height/2) -s;

Comment: I have noticed the approach is good but not working with width only. Please check the https://jsfiddle.net/dyuwg56c/2/

Comment: i have already tried same with the y position and planesSize = planes.node().getBBox().height.. but that was also not working properly.. I'm not Math and Trigonometry expert. So i will wait for the better solution but till than i have tried to change the delta function which almost better than previous one... https://jsfiddle.net/2gzeameo/1/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"that was also not working properly"*, since my fiddle is clearly working. Anyway, do that, wait for someone else writing a *better solution*. Good luck.

Comment: Bro, there are 4 planes running between locations. 3 planes are moving exactly over path but 1 plane is not, that is still moving parallel with the path.. This is what i mean.Please check the paths between Mumbai and Kolkata. You can check on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2gzeameo/ Thanks

Comment: To be more clear I have updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2gzeameo/2/ in which i have removed 1 path and it's plane.

Comment: This is **another** issue. I clearly answered your original question, which was positioning the plane over the line. I won't waste more time and energy in this question. Again, good luck.

Comment: Bro this is not the another issue. It's the same issue that planes are not moving over path. You've already given enough of your time, don't waste your time and energy. Thank you. I have already made it working by using your tricks with other code as given in https://jsfiddle.net/2gzeameo/1/ .But still i think it's the patchy solution.